# MPAndroidChart: Give some offset for Y axis

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to move the Y axis line to be between the values displayed in the chart, not where the values are displayed.
I tried putting offsets but that did not have the wanted effect.

[image: https://imgur.com/ijNBbK5]

```
YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);
xAxis.enableGridDashedLine(10f,15f,10f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0;i < 11;i++) {
    LimitLine ll = new LimitLine(i + 0.5f);
    ll.setLineColor(getColor(R.color.C5));
    ll.enableDashedLine(10f,5f,4f);
    xAxis.addLimitLine(ll);
}
```

The library has LimitLine which is basically what I needed. So I created a dashed limit line at half the distance between 2 values (0.5f) and added them to the `xAxis`.

Comment: Done! Sorry for that